# Ruby on Rails - Adding data to model from Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to implement a tag/category system using [tag-it](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it), but I'm unsure the best method I should be using to pass the data back to the model.

Currently what I'm trying to do is using ajax to call `add_tag` and pass the `tagLabel`.

// application.js

```
$("#tags").tagit({
    beforeTagAdded: function(event, ui) {
        // do something special
        $.ajax({
          url: "add_tag",
          data : {name: ui.tagLabel }
      });
    }
});
```

And within my controller, I just add the param and save it.

// posts_controller.rb

```
  def add_tag
    @post.category_list.add( params[:name] )
    @post.save
  end
```

While this works for existing `posts`, I can't use this method for new `posts`.

And it makes my routes.rb file cluttered if I plan to use this method on multiple models.

// routes.rb

```
get '/posts/:id/add_tag' => 'posts#add_tag', as: :post_add_tag
```

Thanks for your help.